# how to create an array in javascript with values of a resultset

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp

I want to pass the values of the resultset obtained from JSP to arrays in Javascript. Please help me.

```
JSP code that fetches data from database:
ResultSet resultset12 = 
            statement12.executeQuery("select * from(select HOST_NAME,INSTANCE_NAME,PID,PCPU, to_char(TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from ORA_CPU_STATUS where trunc(TIME)=trunc(sysdate) order by PCPU desc) where rownum<=10");

Following are the 2 resultsets, whose values I want to put in 2 arrays in javascript:
 resultset12.getString(2) and resultset12.getString(4)

javascript array format that i want:
var input = [34.4, 62.5, 80.1, 70, 69.6, 69.5, 89.1, 68.4, 18, 17.3] and
categories = ['orcl1 ','orcl2 ','orcl3 ','orcl4 ','orcl5 ','orcl6 ','orcl7 ','orcl8 ','orcl9 ','orcl10 ']
```

Comment: Have you tried looping through the resultset and storing each element into an array slot? It shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: for a novice it is... however i tried putting it like following:

List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
while(resultset12.next()) {
    results.add(resultset12.getString(4));
}

 %>
 var input = [results]

Comment: It seems like if you change "var input = [results]" to simply "var input = results" then you will have your array in var input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Chad, it worked with

```
var dincpu = <%=csv%>;
var dinpcat = <%=csvWithQuote%>;
```

Putting the entire code for reference.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*, java.io.*, java.util.Date, java.util.*,javax.servlet.*, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Calendar " %>
<%  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); %>
 <%
     Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@RAC1.dinu.com:1521:orcl2","cog","cog123");
     Statement statement12 = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet resultset12 = 
            statement12.executeQuery("select * from(select INSTANCE_NAME,PCPU from ORA_CPU_STATUS order by PCPU desc) where rownum<=10");


List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
while(resultset12.next())
{
    String val = resultset12.getString(1);
    list.add(val);
    String val2 = resultset12.getString(2);
    list2.add(val2);

}

String csv = list2.toString();
String csvWithQuote = list.toString().replace("[", "['").replace("]", "']").replace(", ", "','");

%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/2a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/3a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/json2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var dincpu=<%=csv%>;
    var dinpcat = <%=csvWithQuote%>;
    var input = dincpu,
        data = [],
        categories =dinpcat;
        $.each(input, function(index, value){
            var color;
            if (value > 80) color = 'red';
            else if (value > 60) color = 'Orange';
            else color = 'green';
            data.push({y:value, color: color, url:'https://www.google.com'});
        });

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'COL',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Current Top 10 CPU Consumers',
            style: {fontSize: '10px'}
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories,
            labels: {
                rotation: -35,
                align: 'center'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage',
                style: {fontSize: '11px'}
            }
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>' +'- Oracle User Process CPU Consumed :'+'<b>'+ this.y +' % ' +'</b>' ;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            location.href = this.options.url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'CPU Consumed',
            pointWidth: 28,
            data: data

        }]
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="COL" style="min-width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good to hear, nice work! Sorry I wasn't more helpful, just not that familiar myself with resultsets.

Comment: @Chad, it happened all because of you, it compelled me to study more on the subject and search different examples and another member Barbara also helped me... So all the factors are responsible for me to reach at this state. Thanks to both of you...

Comment: Not a problem, I'm glad I could help! It's a good feeling getting to an accomplished point with something you have been struggling with :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*, java.io.*, java.util.Date, java.util.*,javax.servlet.*, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Calendar " %>
<%  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Top 10 CPU</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/2a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/3a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/json2.js"></script>
 <script>
 <%
     Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@RAC1.dinu.com:1521:orcl2","cog","cog123");
     Statement statement12 = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet resultset12 = 
            statement12.executeQuery("select * from(select HOST_NAME,INSTANCE_NAME,PID,PCPU, to_char(TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from ORA_CPU_STATUS where trunc(TIME)=trunc(sysdate) order by PCPU desc) where rownum<=10");
 %>
$(function () {
    var chart;

<%
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
while(resultset12.next())
{
    String val = resultset12.getString(1);
    list.add(val);
    String val2 = resultset12.getString(2);
    list2.add(val2);

}

String csv = list2.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", ",");

String csvWithQuote = list.toString().replace("[", "'").replace("]", "'").replace(", ", "','");


%>

   var input = JSON.parse("[" + <%out.print(csv);%> + "]"),
    data = [],
    categories = JSON.parse("[" + <%out.print(csvWithQuote);%> + "]");
    $.each(input, function(index, value){
        var color;
        if (value > 80) color = 'red';
        else if (value > 60) color = 'Orange';
        else color = 'green';
        data.push({y:value, color: color, url:'https://www.google.com'});
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'COL',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Current Top 10 CPU Consumers',
                    style: {fontSize: '10px'}
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: JSON.parse(categories),
                labels: {
                    rotation: -35,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            },
           yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage',
                    style: {fontSize: '11px'}
                }
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false },
             legend: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>' +'- Oracle User Process CPU Consumed :'+'<b>'+ this.y +' % ' +'</b>' ;
                }
            },
       plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            location.href = this.options.url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
                series: [{
                name: 'CPU Consumed',
                pointWidth: 28,
                data: JSON.parse(data)

            }]
        });
    });
});


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="COL" style="min-width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My problem now is I am not able to pass the JSP Array to the javascript variable, as given below:

```
   var input = JSON.parse("[" + <%out.print(csv);%> + "]"),
    data = [],
    categories = JSON.parse("[" + <%out.print(csvWithQuote);%> + "]");
```

The above javascript code should contain the values like below, then only my graph would work:

```
   var input = [34.4, 62.5, 80.1, 70, 69.6, 69.5, 89.1, 68.4, 18, 17.3],
    data = [],
    categories = ['orcl1 ','orcl2 ','orcl3 ','orcl4 ','orcl5 ','orcl6 ','orcl7 ','orcl8 ','orcl9 ','orcl10 '];
```

@Chad, need your guidance on it.

Comment: It looks like your problem there is how you are accessing your Java variable to set it inside your JS var. Instead of <%out.print(csv);%> I believe that you need to do <%=csv%>. So you would have this: var input = JSON.parse("[" + <%=csv%> + "]"),
    data = [],
    categories = JSON.parse("[" + <%=csvWithQuote%> + "]");

Comment: @Chad I tried doing so, but its not generating the graph. Any idea how I can do.

Comment: @Chad, the <%=csv%> and <%=csvWithQuote%> are returning empty [].

Comment: Are you sure that csv and csvWithQuote are getting set here: `String csv = list2.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", ",");
String csvWithQuote = list.toString().replace("[", "'").replace("]", "'").replace(", ", "','");` Also, I'm beginning to think that since you already have these as Strings, you do not need to use JSON.parse, as it is not in JSON format.

Comment: I am getting the value when I am printing it in the body of the html or within the <% %> "scriptlet" seperately in another jsp page. But when I am combining the scriptlet and the javascript, its returning me empty [].